# Stylus: How to automatically re-compile all files importing the modified styl file?

Tags: gulp, stylus

I'm stucked in this situation:

Suppose: `foo.styl`, `bar.styl`, `basic.styl`

In `foo.styl` and `bar.styl`, they both `@import "basic"`.

I'm wonder how these two files can be automatically re-compiled once `basic.styl` is modified?

It seems WebStorm File Watcher handles this well out of the box, but how it can be achieved in gulp?

Another scenario:

- `foo.styl` --> `@import "bar"`
- `bar.styl` --> `@import "basic"`
- Now `basic.styl` is getting modified.

How to make both `foo` and `bar` re-compiled in the proper order, i.e. `basis -> bar -> foo`?

Thanks a lot.